# Telerik MVC Grid Filter

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I was using Telerik MVC Grid in my project. I just wanted to change the dropdown value orders a bit. I googled for the requirement and found the filter dropdown options are handled by **telerik.grid.min.js file. But, I dont know how can i change the order from

**Options by Default**

```
Is Equal to
Is not equal to
Starts with
Contains
Does not contain
Ends with
```

**Change to the below format**

```
Contains
Does not contain
Starts with
Ends with
Is Equal to
Is not equal to
```

Can anybody tell me the possibilities that i can change the order of filter dropdown box ..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by JQuery simply by some codes like this :

```
$('#GRIDID').find(".t-filter").click(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".t-filter-operator").html('<option value="substringof">Contains</option><option value="notsubstringof">Does not contain</option>');
            });
});
```

NOTE : the above code is a sample, you should do a process to check what operators you have and then repopulate the items in desired order. You can find all allowed "`option`" tags by inspecting the rendered grid.

Comment: Modified code. **$('.t-grid').find(".t-filter").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".t-filter-operator:contains('Contains')").html('<option value="substringof">Contains</option><option value="notsubstringof">Does not contain</option><option value="startswith">Starts with</option><option value="endswith">Ends with</option><option value="eq">Is equal to</option><option value="ne">Is not equal to</option>');
        });
    });**. The code works fine but sometimes the repopulate happens only on the second time when we click on the filter box. any solution ..?

Comment: call the setTimeout with more delay. for example call it : setTimeout(function(){...} , 10); It may solve your problem. Let me know it

Comment: Still some of the filter box shows with default values but not with reloaded order of items.

Comment: did you test it with more delay? like 50, 60, 100 instead of 10 ? Although it is not the best approach, it should solve your problem. The reason of mentioned situation is your code runs sooner than  Telerik's related source codes.

Comment: Yes I tested with all the above delay time. Atleast one filter stops reordering of the Items.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (if you're using MVC razor syntax)

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>().Columns(columns => 
{
   columns.Bound(x => x.variableName);
})
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
                                .Extra(false)
                                 .Operators(operators => operators
                                    .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                                        .Contains("Contains").DoesNotContain("DoesNotContain").WhateverYouNeed)
                                    .ForEnums( dat => dat.Clear()
                                        .IsEqualTo("Is Equal To"))
                                    ))
```

Here, the Clear() empties the options in the filter and then you can add the ones you want or even create your own custom ones there, simply place them there in the order that you want.

Have fun!